# Visualize text file with location info and intensity

Tags: gis, data-visualization, gdal

I have an ascii text file containing location data (column 9-lat and 10-long) and intensity(column 20)

```
 200010  207  020311    40658.5  406593 52 344927.31 7100203.50  -26.2078720  127.4491855 345060.64 7100369.14   26.4  650.3  628.0 55471.293    20.168 55648.817 55637.523  -146.062
```

the text file has many lines 10k+

I am trying to visualize this using GDAL, but not sure how to proceed.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try [QGis](http://www.qgis.org/about-qgis/screenshots.html). It is free software for making maps with data.

GDAL is for doing sophisticated data transformations.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is named `viz.txt`, then you can extract
and plot the data using the following commands:

```
$ awk '{print $9, $10, $20}' < viz.txt > viz2.txt
$ gnuplot
```

...

```
gnuplot> plot "viz2.txt" with points palette
```

This will give you a chart, nicely coloured by intensity.

If you want a more interactive solution, or to overlay the
data on a map, then you will have to use GIS software such
as ArcView, MapInfo or the free tools Generic Mapping Tools (GMT) or QGIS.